# Maximum of a convex function in an interval

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function. Does $f$ have a maximum in $[a,b]$?.

I have thought that if $f$ is not continous at $x=a$ or $x=b$ then I can find a counterexample for which it does not exist a global maximum. The same thing for minimum. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is convex, then it is continuous (and therefore upper semicontinuous) on $(a,b)$.

I claim that $f$ is upper semicontinuous at $a$ and $b$. If $x \to a$ from the right, we can write $x = \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b$, then by convexity
$$f(x) \leq \lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b),$$
and therefore
$$\limsup_{x \to a} f(x) \leq \limsup_{\lambda \to 1}(\lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b)) = f(a).$$
A similar argument works for $x \to b$ from the left.

Since $f$ is upper semicontinuous on the compact set $[a,b]$, it attains a maximum. (Intuitively, the idea here is that if $f$ is discontinuous at an end point, the discontinuity must be an "upward jump" in order to preserve convexity.)

But $f$ need not attain a minimum. For example, consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (x-b)^2, \ \ x \in [a,b)\\ 1, \ \ x=b.  \end{cases}$$

Comment: How prove the idea for the maximum?

Comment: @pawel [Have a look at this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698452/maximum-of-a-upper-semicontinuous-function#1698489)